# Merging and updating dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have 2 dataframes,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a', 'A',], 'value': [1, 1,]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B'], 'value': [5, 6,]})
```

The dataframes have the same columns, but different rows.

df1:

```
key   value
a     1
A     1
```

df2:

```
key   value
A     5
B     6
```

I want the resulting dataframe to be:

df3:

```
key   value
a     1
A     5
B     6
```

It is kinda like `dict.update()`. If the key is already in there, update a new value; otherwise, add a new key and a new value. But how do I do it with dataframe?

And I don't want to do anything with the suffix'_x''_y', because in reality I have about 2 key columns and 10+ value columns.

Forgive me if this problem is too simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `combine_first()` method of `pandas`.

> Update null elements with value in the same location in other.
>
> Combine two DataFrame objects by filling null values in one DataFrame
> with non-null values from other DataFrame. The row and column indexes
> of the resulting DataFrame will be the union of the two. The resulting
> dataframe contains the ‘first’ dataframe values and overrides the
> second one values where both first.loc[index, col] and
> second.loc[index, col] are not missing values, upon calling
> first.combine_first(second).

Read documentation of [combine_first()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) here.

Here's the working code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a', 'A'], 'value': [1, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B'], 'value': [5, 6]})

# Set the 'key' column as the index for both dataframes
df1.set_index('key', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('key', inplace=True)

# merge both dataframes
df3 = df2.combine_first(df1).reset_index()

print(df3)
```

Here's the output:

```
  key  value
0   A      5
1   B      6
2   a      1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could get this done by using the `merge` function and setting the `how` parameter to "outer" to perform an outer join on the `key` column, combining the data from both dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a', 'A'], 'value': [1, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B'], 'value': [5, 6]})

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', how='outer')
```

you can then use the `fillna` method to fill NaN values with the non-null values from the other column, and create a new column `value` containing the updated values

```
df3['value'] = df3['value_y'].fillna(df3['value_x'])
df3 = df3[['key', 'value']]
```

Comment: The thing is I have many value cololumns, like value1, value2, ... value14, I guess I can't fillna with every column right?